# Why is my IList read-only?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, ilist

I'm making a game. I search through all child components in an object and make a list from it, then I remove the first entry because I do not want it. An error occurs when I try to remove the first entry. There seems to be nothing on google about this, everything is HOW to make it read-only.

I get this error:

```
NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only
System.Array.InternalArray__RemoveAt (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Array.cs:147)
(wrapper managed-to-managed) UnityEngine.Transform[]:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1.RemoveAt (int)
PlayerEquipper.Start () (at Assets/PlayerEquipper.cs:27)
```

This is my code:

```
private IList<Transform> characterChilds = new List<Transform>();
private IList<Transform> armorChilds = new List<Transform>();
private IList<Transform> glovesChilds = new List<Transform>();
private IList<Transform> bootsChilds = new List<Transform>();



void Start()
{
    characterChilds = new List<Transform>();
    characterChilds = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    Debug.Log(characterChilds[0]);
    characterChilds.RemoveAt(0);
    Debug.Log(characterChilds[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of yours:

```
characterChilds = new List<Transform>();
```

Creates a mutable list.  However, the following line:

```
characterChilds = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
```

Overwrites that list, and so the previous line is useless.  Clearly, `GetComponentsInChildren` returns an `IList` that is not modifiable.  If you really want to start from the result of that method call and still be able to modify the list, you can try:

```
characterChilds = new List<Transform>(transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>());
```

Now, you can remove items from that list, but without more context, I'm not certain that will do exactly what you're hoping for.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what's happening now, and your solution worked perfectly. Will accept your answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the `GetComponentsInChildren` method returns an immutable collection. You can try the following to workaround it:

```
characterChilds = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();
```